# “End-of-story mark”

Tags: macros, symbols, typography, decorations

I try to get in the last line of all my document a black square to mark the end of article.

So, this is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\useppackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}%
\newcommand\finisarticulus{\,$\blacksquare$}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit.\finisarticulus{}
\end{document}
```

So, I get a good rendering:

[image]

But this simple and idealistic situation don’t always appear.

If I use, TOC, bibliography, or glossary at the end, I can’t control where the *finis articulus* will appear.

For example, with bibliography, I have the following `main.tex` as MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}%

\newcommand\finisarticulus{\,$\blacksquare$}

\bibliography{bibli.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit.

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography\finisarticulus{}
\end{document}
```

And this is his `bibli.bib`:

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

I compile the project with `xelatex main.tex; bibtex main ; xelatex main.tex`, then I get this ugly rendering:

[image]

When I was wondering something like:

[image]

So, is it possible to force LaTeX to add something just after the last word of the document as if this word was produced by the TOC, the bibliography, the glossary or other kind of macro? And then how?

Comment: The main problem is that the paragraph is formatted before it is added to the page.  \AtEndDocument will start a new paragraph, and \everypar adds stuff to the beginning of a paragraph, not the end.

Comment: If you don't add an empty line between the last paragraph of regular text and `\

Comment: If you don't add an empty line between the last paragraph of regular text and `\end{document}`, then `\AtEndDocument` will not start a new paragraph, so you could say, in the preamble, `\AtDocument{\finisarticulus}`. However, that won't work with a bibtex-generated bibliography, since it consists of a list of `\bibitem`s. Here, the only way I can see is to manually edit the generated .bbl file. Append the `\finisarticulus` to the last entry. If you don't run bibtex afterwards, your manual edit will not be overwritten.